# How can I hide or show the inner level

Tags: jquery, html

I want When clicked on one li, ul inside it, if the invisible،become visible (only the first level) and become hidden if they are visible
For example 
If you click on #2 if #3 is hidden ,become show and if #3 is show, become hidden
How can I hide or show the inner level?

```js
$(".accordion li").click(function(e){
    if($(this).find("> ul").is(":visible"))
  $(this).find("> ul").hide(); 
 else
  $(this).find("> ul").show();
});
$(".accordion li:has(> ul)").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).find("> a").removeAttr("href");
});
```

```css
.accordion{font-family:'byekan';display:block}.accordion>ul>li{cursor:pointer;background-color:#2980b9;font-size:1.5rem;color:#fff}.accordion>ul>li:hover{background-color:#3498db}.accordion>ul>li:not(:last-of-type){border-bottom:1px solid #fff}.accordion>ul>li>a{display:inline-block;padding:15px}.accordion>ul>li>ul>li{cursor:pointer;background-color:#2c3e50;font-size:1.1rem;color:#fff}.accordion>ul>li>ul>li:hover{background-color:#34495e}.accordion>ul>li>ul>li>a{display:inline-block;padding:10px}.accordion>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li{cursor:pointer;background-color:#27ae60;font-size:.9rem;color:#ddd}.accordion>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li:hover{background-color:#2ecc71}.accordion>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li>a{display:inline-block;padding:6px}.accordion>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li{cursor:pointer;background-color:#16a085;font-size:.9rem;color:#fff}.accordion>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li:hover{background-color:#1abc9c}.accordion>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li>a{display:inline-block;padding:4px}.accordion ul{display:inline}.accordion ul li{list-style:none}.accordion ul li a{color:#fff}.accordion ul li a:hover{color:#eee}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="accordion">
    <ul>
        <li><a>#1</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a>#2</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>#2</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>#1</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a>#2</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">#4</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="">#4</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: why not just hide show with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you edited, now I see what you mean, so I edited my answer.

Is as simple as this:

```js
$('li').on('click',function(e){
  
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="accordion">
    <ul>
        <li><a>#1</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a>#2</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>#2</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>#1</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a>#2</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">#3</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">#4</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="">#4</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

You need to use event stopPropagation because if you dont, then events from containers li will fire click events.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change javascript code as follows. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qc8pwkyb/)

js :

```
$(".accordion li:has(> ul)").each(function (index, element) {
    $(this).find("> a").removeAttr("href");
});

$(".accordion li a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle(300);
});
```